# jQuery scrollTop on Ajax page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

The pagination on the list product page on my site reload with Ajax when clicked.

I want to add a jQuery event that fires when a page is selected with the pagination. It should scroll the user to the top of the page. This is what I have so far, unfortunately it only fires once.

```
$( "li.page.curved_mini" ).on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
});
```

Comment: Please provide more of your code. Namely your AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the li.page is being replaced by the ajax load and your event is not being re-bound to the newly replaced element. Try:

```
$('body').on('click', "li.page.curved_mini", function() {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
});
```

This will bind the event to the body element (which won't be replaced) but still only fire of the li is clicked, and will remain even after the li is replaced via an ajax load.

Comment: This does not appear to be working. Unlike the previous code this doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Can you setup a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem which I can adapt?

Answer (score 0):

The ajax has a disability, after he had his return he kinda ignores events with class and id.

You can fix it with [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or onclick = ""

I prefer to use onclick

```
<a onclick="scrollUp()">...</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollUp() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
    }
</script>
```